# Understanding parts of this PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am sorry guys that I am not an Expert of PCB and I am still a learner so please answer this question.
i want to know which parts have been used in this PCB.
this device is used to automatic Starting of an Engine starter, but i guess my question is very simple.

[image]

Comment: Please, take better pictures of the circuit. A suggestion: disable your camera flash and try to illuminate the circuit with light coming from a shallow angle (small LED flashlight work a treat), this usually makes the laser-etched writings on the chips stand out much better. The illumination angle must be found by trial and error.

Comment: Or just write them down

Comment: @Passerby trivial, assuming the OP doesn't mistake a symbol or the writings are confused. Maybe a better photo is the safest bet.

Comment: This Device is not in my own house, I took this picture from somebody else house. sorry for that

Comment: The 8 pin dil chip (3) seems to have OTA1?1 (middle digit obscured by red line, op amp possibly?) beside it and the 8 pin dil looks to be from DIGITECH but without identification numbers who can tell.

Comment: Man you answered me perfectly that these both are DIL chips and I told you I am beginner and I am learning about basic electronics now I can research how DIL chips works Thank you

Comment: @Jim Dearden can you tell me where and why we use DILs?

Comment: DIL stands for dual in line - its just the package a lot of chips were put into. You cannot tell what is inside by the external package. Its just a way of connecting a 'chip' to the outside world through a set of metal pins (standard size and spacing) coming from a rigid plastic body. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unknown, bad picture
2. Mechanical relay.
3. Unknown, no text visible due to flash.
4. Trim potentiometer.
5. See 3.
6. Likely a Regulator considering the large input cap and the smaller output cap next to it, no text visible.

Anything specific can't be known without the part numbers which aren't visible in your picture.

Comment: can you tell me what is difference between transistor and regulator or can simply explain what regulator does?

Comment: A transistor is a single electronic component - it needs other parts around it to make a useful circuit. A regulator (short for "Voltage Regulator") is an integrated circuit that produces a controlled voltage output from a varying (and usually higher) input voltage.  It would include several transistors and other components.  Many voltage regulators are three pin devices that may look like power transistors.

Comment: @PeterBennett Bennett Then why we don't use step down transformers or resistors instead of Regulator?

Comment: @Andriopak: Resistors are often used to reduce voltage, but the voltage drop across a resistor will vary with current (see Ohm's Law).  A voltage regulator will produce a constant voltage output regardless of the current drawn, provided that the current is within its capability. Transformers can be used to step down an AC voltage, but the output voltage will depend on both the input voltage and current drawn.

Comment: @PeterBennett you are Great my Dear. thank you for the information and do you know how to make PCBs? I know this is really not good question but if you know the tools which required for making pcbs please tell me

Comment: @Andriopak: comments are intended to refer to the question or answer they follow.  If you have a new question, not directly relating to the current topic, you should post a new question.  But first, search this site for an answer, as there have been many questions on making PC boards.